# Can i call a method that takes IEnumerable<Baseclass<superclass>> with IEnumerable<Derivedclass<subclass>>

Tags: c#, .net, oop, .net-core

I have some code that's equivalent to this (though this is a simplification):

```
namespace AnimalHospital
{
    public class Animal { }
    public class Dog : Animal { }
    public class Cat : Animal { }

    public interface Vet<T> where T : Animal 
    { 
        void takeCareOf(T animal); 
    }
    public abstract class SpecializedDogVet<T> : Vet<T> where T : Dog
    {
       public abstract void takeCareOf(T dog); 
    }

    public abstract class SpecializedCatVet<T> : Vet<T> where T : Cat
    {
        public abstract void takeCareOf(T cat);
    }

    public class AnimalHospital
    {
        public IList<SpecializedCatVet<Cat>> CatVets = new List<SpecializedCatVet<Cat>>();
        public IList<SpecializedDogVet<Dog>> DogVets = new List<SpecializedDogVet<Dog>>();

        private void treatSickAnimal(IEnumerable<Vet<Animal>> vets, Animal patient)
        {
            foreach(var vet in vets)
            {
                vet.takeCareOf(patient);
            }
        }

        public void treatSickCat(Cat cat)
        {
            treatSickAnimal(CatVets, cat);
        }

        public void treatSickDog(Dog dog)
        {
            treatSickAnimal(DogVets, dog);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error, telling me that conversion from:

`IList<SpecializedCatVet<Cat>>` to `IEnumerable<Vet<Animal>>` is not possible.  How can this be? Before this they were nonegeneric, and i had some other problems, as i could not override the vet interfaces takeCareOf method. I had expected that as IEnumerable of Animal can easily be instantiated with a list of Dog, the same would be the case with parsing a collection of generics as long as their type parameter is a derirative of the required type. This is not the case though, and I seem unable to figure out why, or how to do this properly.

Thanks for reading.

UPDATE: I'm Accepting JLRishe's answer, makes perfect sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: An easy way to see if the `IEnumerable` is linked to your problem is to use `.AsEnumerable()` from `System.Linq` before calling `treatSickAnimal` (`treatSickAnimal(DogVets.AsEnumerable*(), dog)`). No link? Drop it in your sample :)

Comment: No, I knew from the outset that the Collection type wasn't the problem, but rather the type parameters, i just did not understand why :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not allowed, because if it were allowed, you could something like this:

```
var cat = new Cat();

treatSickAnimal(DogVets, cat);
```

And essentially try to force dog vets to treat a cat.

You can remedy this by making your methods generic on the animal parameter:

```
private void treatSickAnimal<T>(IEnumerable<Vet<T>> vets, T patient) where T : Animal
{
    foreach (var vet in vets)
    {
        vet.takeCareOf(patient);
    }
}
```

This should allow your code to compile correctly and ensure that you don't try to force any dog vets to treat cats.

---

Side note note - unless you plan on having specialized types (subclasses) of `Dog` and `Cat` and vets that are specialized for those subclasses, you can simplify the definition of `SpecializedDogVet` and `SpecializedCatVet` to be like this:

```
public abstract class SpecializedDogVet : Vet<Dog>
{
    public abstract void takeCareOf(Dog dog);
}

public abstract class SpecializedCatVet : Vet<Cat>
{
    public abstract void takeCareOf(Cat cat);
}
```

You would then refer to the types like this:

```
public IList<SpecializedCatVet> CatVets = new List<SpecializedCatVet>();
public IList<SpecializedDogVet> DogVets = new List<SpecializedDogVet>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the sidenote. Very helpful. I did not know :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant because your `Vet<T>` interface is currently invariant, notice you can make it contravariant by specifying that it is input parameter like so:

```
public interface Vet<in T> where T : Animal
{
    void takeCareOf(T animal);
}
```

This is possible because everywhere `T` is used as **in**put parameter.

In order your code to compile you can do what @JLRishe said, or you can change your logic and make `T` **out**put parameter, but in order to do that you need to change your `Vet` implementation so everywhere `T` is used it needs to be in position of output just an example:

```
public interface Vet<out T> where T : Animal
{
    T takeCareOf();
}
```

So in conclusion, you can pass base class to interfaces or delegates where they have type parameters defined as **out**put and you can pass more derived classes when type parameters are defined as **in**put.

This is actually AMAZING article for covariance and contravariance if I got you hooked you should definitely check it http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Comment: Making `T` an `out` parameter doesn't make any sense in this case because `T takeCareOf()` doesn't make any sense. Is the vet supposed to conjure an animal out of thin air?

Comment: @JLRishe it was not my point saying what makes any sense, but rather show him why it didn't compile at first place. *Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime*

Comment: Fair enough. Definitely worthwhile to elaborate on how `in` and `out` work and how they affect the way in which generic classes can be used, but if you're going to do so, I think it also makes sense to explain why those wouldn't be applicable to OP's situation.